# when I set allowscriptaccess param to always my flash component disappear?

Tags: javascript, swfobject

When I set allowscriptaccess param to always using below code my Flash component disappear?!
but when I comment it it work.
I have ExternalInterface.call in my Action script so I think I should set this param to always.
How can I fix this problem?

`var so = new SWFObject("dresscaillou_fa.swf", "dresscaillou_fa", "560", "330", "5,0,0,0", "#ffffff");
so.addParam("play", true);
so.addparam("allowscriptaccess","");
so.write("flashcontent");                                   params.allowscriptaccess = "always";`